# Can't access child Data Categories

Tags: apex, dynamic, data-category

I'm trying to get all Data Categories from an Article Type through the varius describe calls I've found in the documentation such as https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult.htm

This is the code I'm using, running it through Anonymous Apex

```
List <DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair> pairs = 
      new List<DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair>();

DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair pair1 = 
      new DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair();
pair1.setSobject('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
pair1.setDataCategoryGroupName('MyArticles');

pairs.add(pair1);

List<Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult>results = 
      Schema.describeDataCategoryGroupStructures(pairs, true);
          for(Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult r : results){
              System.debug(r.getName()); //'MyArticles'
              Schema.DataCategory[] topCategories = r.getTopCategories();
              for(Schema.DataCategory c : topCategories){
                  System.debug(c.getName()); //'All'
                  Schema.DataCategory[] subCats = c.getChildCategories();
                  System.debug(subCats); //empty, why?
                  for(Schema.DataCategory sc: subCats){
                      System.debug(sc.getName()); //Never reached
                  }
              }
          }
```

My Data Categories are structured with one 'All' Category at the top level, which I can find using `getTopCategories()`, but when I call `getChildCategories()`on the result, I get an empty list, despite the fact that I have 5 child categories set up under it. I made sure Data Category Visibility is on, but I still get no results. Is there any other reason I wouldn't be able to see these subcategories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the ",true)" in the method call for describeDataCategoryGroupStructures stands for "topCategoriesOnly"

[System.Schema.describeDataCategoryGroupStructures](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm#apex_System_Schema_describeDataCategoryGroupStructures)

Turn this to false, and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
<knowledge:categoryList categoryVar="category" categoryGroup="{!CategoryName}" rootCategory="All" level="1">
         <a href="/apex/vf_SubCategoryTopics?ptype={!CategoryName}&sctype={!category.Name}"> <apex:outputText value="{!category.Label}" /> </a>
        <br />


        <br />
     <!--    <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!LPAD(' ',6*category.depth,'&nbsp;')}" /> -->


        </knowledge:categoryList>
```

You can make the level="-1" to get unlimited category.  for level ="1" it will just give you the sub category.
The  tag works  like loop and gets what you need! Worked for me while working for a knowledge base:    Please mark my answer accepted if it works !

If you need any other help refer to this guide 
[This links is all about the knowledge base development](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_dev_guide.pdf)